# How do i install Android NDK on Windows OS? without any Unix Linux stuff the easy way?

Tags: android, installation, android-ndk

I am struggling to install the Android NDK on windows for a few day's , can someone explain the easy way with image tutorial and explanations how to install it?

How i would be able to use the C/C++ in my Android applications???

PS: I do not know how to use Linux / Unix , so please do not refer me Linux implementations,
I have read all the tutorials in

[Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) and [another one](http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2010/05/android-sdk-ndk-part-1-setting-up-your-environment/) and [another one](http://www.crystax.net/?locale=en)....

Thanks in advance... any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Its given in the link that you specified. You just have to unzip into a folder and you will be able to work with NDK.

Comment: Without any additional install that i have to do?

Comment: Yeah. i mean if you want emulator & stuff. you have to install Android SDK too. I will be pretty simple I see you are just worried.

Comment: @Dave thanks i will try it, but how do build the project with native code implemented into java code?

Comment: Try to build a project from sample directory.

Comment: There's nothing easy about NDK, you should read the documentation carefully. I don't know how would you be able to program in C++ for Android not knowing anything about Unix/Linux. Take it easy and go step by step.

Comment: If you are in windows 7. Go to project directory -> Hold shift and right click -> Open Command prompt here. Then just execute `ndk-build`. if the ndk path is not in your environment variable, then you have to write the full path for `ndk-build`.

Comment: @IamStalker, just read the SDK page they gave a sample code and first try to make your feet wet. I am not sure about building C or C++ in Android though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refer to this [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/). You need cygwin to start doing C/C++ development on window.

In my opinion, I am afraid there is no easy way going Android NDK on window. My experience with Android NDK on window was terrible. Thus I move to Ubuntu at the end.

Comment: Me too. I tried on windows but at last moved to linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: @PH7 could i use it with Virtual Machine and Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, you certainly can use VM to do. I am also using VMware Player and Virtual Box to do those.

Comment: @PH7 Can you refer me to an installation example or something that i can use to implement "native code" ?

Comment: @lamStalker,  have u checked out the link i gave in my answer? That is a simple enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid all Linux and Linux-like (e.g. Cygwin & friends), take a look at [vs-android](http://code.google.com/p/vs-android/)

Comment: Currently doing 99% of my Android development in Linux/Eclipse. The most I have done with vs-android is "take it for a spin".

Comment: i haven't been successful with the installation of this component, it's give's me strange error, like PATH variables aren't okey, even after i have done what they requested on the installation manual. Might you suggest me what should i do with this?